# How can I prevent "zend_mm_heap corrupted" when adding Views programmatically?

Tags: views

I have created a module that has 150 views added to mymodule.views_default.inc.

At first I could not get this to load as I was running out of memory. After increasing my memory to a sufficient limit, I now always get the error:

```
zend_mm_heap corrupted
```

Has anyone encountered this before while adding views to their modules?

Comment: This probably isn't going to be Drupal related as such (the specific error at least), have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247977/what-does-zend-mm-heap-corrupted-mean?

Comment: yea, that and others that also talk about memcached possibly being the issue I saw a lot of, but solutions for either came up empty. Searching for drupal zend_mm_heap corrupted came up with bugs posted on php.net with drupal sites as the source, but those were dead ends as well. If I turn off my module, or delete that file, the problem goes away.

Comment: If this appears to be a case of Drupal not playing nice with zend, have you opened an issue on D.O.?

Comment: Out of curiosity, which Zend are you using?  One of my dev servers which has several sites on it is Zend CE 5.2, and I have never seen this error before.

Comment: @MPD how do I figure that out? Running Ubuntu LAMP stack with PHP 5.3

Comment: Not sure.  I explicitly installed the yum packages from  zend.com for my version of CentOS.

Answer (score 1):

There are several bugs reported to php.net about this error (search "drupal zend_mm_heap corrupted). Indeed it turned out to be a PHP bug with php 5.3.

I upgraded to php 5.4 and the error goes away.

The issue is not necessarily Drupal related. However, it does seem to be related to how php includes and processes large files. In that respect, since Drupal can end up dealing with massive amounts of files and php data, this is probably the reason that many of the reported PHP bugs involved Drupal sites.

So, if you are getting this error, quite possibly you need to upgrade your PHP to 5.4